# How do I call a function from an Angular Bootstrap modal (using angular-strap)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angular-strap

I'm using Angular JS (with [Angular Strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/)), and I'm trying to get a save confirmation dialog working.

I have a `clear` function which looks like this:

```
$scope.clear = function(confirm) {
  if ($scope.dirty && !confirm) {
    $modal({template: '/save.html', show: true, backdrop: 'static'});
    return;
  } 

  // clear the data
}
```

I then have the following buttons in my modal dialog:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="clear(true);hide()">Discard Changes</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="hide()">Cancel</button>
```

This displays the dialog just fine, and hides it as well, no matter which button I click.  But it never calls the `clear` function.  What's going on?

Comment: I just tested having a function before the hide and it works fine.  http://plnkr.co/edit/uNpZdPPBcLzy33937Mur?p=preview

Comment: Is your clear function created within a controller? Also, could you provide a more complete sample using jsfiddle, plnkr, etc?

Comment: The point where you call hide() function might have been created in a new scope(say, if you've used ng-if). Try using $parent.hide();

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the scope(**$scope**) in the $modal

```
$modal({ 
 template: '/save.html', 
 show: true, 
 backdrop: 'static',
 scope: $scope
});
```

Now you can use **$parent.clear()** or just **clear()** as the scope has been sent to the modal.